# OctoberCMS plugin form database relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms

I am making a plugin on October CMS builder. Created couple db tables, models and forms in backend. Now trying to add form element (checkboxes) and want to make checkbox values to be taken from other table.

Example:

```
Table 1: categories
Model: Categories (relates to table categories)
Columns: id(INT, AI), name(VARCHAR), types(TEXT)

Table 2: types
Model: Types (relates to table types)
Columns: id(INT, AI), type(INT)
```

So in category creation form i want to assign types. For example:

```
Category name: News
Types: 1, 3, 7 (from table: types column: type)
```

How do i make this work?

Comment: October makes use of eloquent for models.  Pretty well documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it. Lookep up in Rainlab plugin for relations and options.

In my Category model i have added a function to fetch required data from other table and it worked.

```
public function getTypesOptions()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple you have to define a function called `getTypesOptions` in your model after creating the field in your `fields.yaml` file.

```
public function getTypesOptions()
{
    return \Namespace\Plugin\Models\Model::all();
}
```

And OctoberCMS is smart enough to handle everything else.

Comment: Your solution is close, but don't qork quite well. I get the list of options, however i only see checkboxes without values.